# Copy the address of all elements using std::copy

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, std

I'm trying to obtain the address of all elements of a given collection and copy them to a std::set. Basically, instead of

```
std::set<T> s1;
std::copy(first1, last1, std::inserter(s1, s1.begin()));
```

I'd like to insert their addresses. Something like:

```
std::set<std::add_pointer<T>> s1;
std::copy(reference_iterator(first1), reference_iterator(last1), 
    std::inserter(s1, s1.begin()));
```

Here, reference_iterator would be an iterator returning the address of its element, instead of the element, something opposed to what the boost indirect_iterator does.
Is there any standard way to do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `std::transform` to copy with modification.

```
std::transform(first1, last1, std::inserter(s1, s1.begin()),
               std::addressof<T>);
```

Comment: See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/478d3456b908b2eb)**